# Visual Studio throws exceptions in System code rather than User Code

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, .net-8.0

Im am working on a C# WPF Project in .Net 8.0 and for some reason I have access to the complete source code of all System assemblies. On most PCs, like my work computer, looking at the definition of classes like `Console` only reveals public methods and xml comments, while my home PC has access to the complete source code, including content of private methods (like I can see the code behind the  `private static void HandlePosixSignal` method within `Console`).

I assume this is the reason that, whenever I get an exception, it isn't thrown in my own code, but rather some system class instead. To demonstrate what I mean, I copied the example of the [MSDN Exception page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2022):

```
  string something = "aa";
  string.Format("{1}", something);
```

Normally this would raise an exception in the `string.Format` call, like you can see in the screenshot from Microsoft:

[image]

In my case - and i assume it's due to having access to the full source code - the error is raised in the `System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader` at `internal static void RewrapException` as you can see here:

[image]

I have no idea how I got access to the decompiled source code or whether it is a default .Net 8 feature, but this is pretty annoying for debugging and I'd like to disable it. Any ideas how I can disable it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's due to the debugging option `Just My Code` in Visual Studio which you need to check.

When enabled this instructs Visual Studio to only load the assemblies you have created and not `System.*` or any other external assemblies when debugging.

To enable it you can use the [Feature Search](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/introducing-a-new-way-to-search-your-code-and-visual-studio-features/) (Shortcut `Ctrl + Q`) and search for `Just My Code` or go to `Options > Debugging > General` and you should see a checkbox labeled *Enable Just My Code* which you have to check. Then restart the debugging process and you should see the exception being thrown where you expect it to.

[image: Visual Studio 2022 - "Just My Code" option]

For more details please see the [Microsoft Documentation - Debug only user code with Just My Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/just-my-code?view=vs-2022)